# Multiply cell values during r.mapcalc in GRASS

Tags: raster, grass-gis, overlay, r.mapcalc

I'm doing some sieve mapping in GRASS. I have several map layers containing various values representing site suitability ranks.

I need to use r.mapcalc to add these maps together for example `map1 + map2 + map3`. However, I need to take into account the weightings of each map layer so during the mapcalc I need the values in each map layer to be multiplied by their respective weight. Is there any way to do this?

In the same way you would do something like `if(isnull(map1), 0, 1) + if(isnull(map2), 0, 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

As the saying goes: "There's more than one way to cook an egg"
Have a look at `r.series`. This module allows to combine a series of raster maps in many ways,  including applying a list of weights.

i.e. (assuming a linux bash command shell:

```
MAP_LIST=`g.list type=rast pattern=map*`
WEIGHTS="0.1,0.2,0.9,0.5"
r.series input=$MAP_LIST method=sum weights=$WEIGHTS ouput=map_sum
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(map1 * weight1) + (map2 * weight2)
```

works!